# How to stop grid from auto scaling with Julia plots

Tags: graph, julia, julia-plots

I'm making a gif using Julia Plots, however, as the frames progress the grid autoscales making it seem very jittery, if anyone knows if I can simply set the exact size of the grid such that it remains stagnant that would be a great help.

```
 scatter(planex, planey, markersize=1.2, aspect_ratio=:equal, xlims=(-2.5,2.5))
```

^ this is the line that plots x and y the values (planex and planey)

[image: This is the gif generated, notice how its slightly resizing during certain frames]

I tried setting the x-limits and aspect ratio expecting it to keep the frames from resizing.
What resulted is that after a large amount of frames the image stops deforming but in earlier parts it still jitters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried also setting `ylims`?